# kivy popup displaying at the end of a running process

Tags: python, kivy

For some process in my app, I use the internet to acquire some data. So for those processed I want a simple popup box(with a text Loading...) to appear at the begining of the process, but when I ran the test code, I observed that the popup box displays at the end of the process rather than at the begining of the process which makes it useless. Here is the test code I am using. Your help is appreciated, thanks.

```
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def popup(self):
        self.pop_up=Popup(title='Loading...')
        self.pop_up.open()

    def popup_done(self):
        self.pop_up.dismiss()

    def ite(self):
        for i in range(100):
            App.get_running_app().root.current='second'
            return i

    def thread_it(self,fx):
        self.popup()
        mythread = threading.Thread(target=fx)
        mythread.start()

    def ite(self,num):
        for i in range(num):
            txt=str(i)*40
            self.ids.lbl.text=txt
            print txt
            #if i==num-1: #this is not working
             #   self.popup_done()

class labelApp(App):

    def build(self):
        pass

labelApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
ScreenManagement:
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                #on_press:root.popup()
                #on_release:root.popup_done()
                on_press:root.thread_it(root.ite(40000))
                on_press:root.current='second'

    Screen:
        name:'second'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                id:lbl
                text: 'hello'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `ScreenManagement.ite()` method. It ***doesn't*** run in thread and you've already noticed that anything that could compete with Kivy's main loop and doesn't run in `Thread` will freeze the main loop. Kivy has [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) which might interest you too.

For this exact code however you'll need [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), which will freeze a function in time and return a thing you can pass as argument, so that it wouldn't be executed in-place where you want to add it as an argument to a thread function (e.g. if `ite()` means executing, `partial` will remove those brackets and let `Thread` add them when it's necessary)

`Thread(target=fx)` means after passing the `ite()` method basically this:

```
Thread(target=root.ite(40000))
```

i.e. runs that thing in-place and as `ite()` method doesn't return anything, it'll do this:

```
# freeze main loop
# after done, call Thread
Thread(target=None)
```

and starts it. So you freeze your main loop and after the `ite()` ends, the `Popup` gets its turn to show up. Let's fix it with `partial`:

```
#:import partial functools.partial
<ScreenManagement>:
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                #on_press:root.popup()
                #on_release:root.popup_done()
                on_press: root.thread_it(partial(root.ite,400))
                on_press: root.current='second'
```